# How to store json data based on certain condition

Tags: angular

How the data looks like

```
0: {id: 1, name: "strter", subscriber: 2500, amount: 0}
1: {id: 2, name: "Pro_2500", subscriber: 2500, amount: 10}
2: {id: 3, name: "Pro_5k", subscriber: 5000, amount: 20}
3: {id: 4, name: "Pro_10k", subscriber: 10000, amount: 30}
4: {id: 14, name: "Enterprise_2500", subscriber: 2500, amount: 100}
5: {id: 15, name: "Enterprise_5k", subscriber: 5000, amount: 110}
6: {id: 16, name: "Enterprise_10k", subscriber: 10000, amount: 120}
```

I have declared 3 properties starter pro and enterprise. All the above data is in the property `allPlans`
I am looking to store all the data to respective properties depending on whether the name is pro, starter or enterprise. So all the data where name is pro should be stored in `pro: any`

```
export class XComponent implements OnInit {
allPlans: any;
starter: any;
pro: any;
enterprise: any;

 constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
    activatedRoute.data.subscribe((res)=>{
      this.allPlans = res.plansresolve.data;
    });
  }
}
```

I tried this and it prints all of them

```
this.pro = this.allPlans.find((x: any)=>{ x.name === "Pro_"; console.log(x.name) })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
activatedRoute.data.subscribe((res)=>{
  this.allPlans = res.plansresolve.data;
  this.allPlans.forEach(p => {
       this.pro = this.allPlans.filter((x: any)=> x.name.includes("Pro_"));
       this.starter = this.allPlans.filter((x: any)=> x.name.includes("starter"));
       this.enterprise = this.allPlans.filter((x: any)=> x.name.includes("Enterprise_"));

   });
});
```

}

or `switch` case is also best

Comment: @natecog, The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.
you have to check for subString not directly 'Pro_'

Answer (score 0):

```
this.pro = this.allPlans.filter((x: any)=>{ x.name.indexOf("Pro_")>-1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the RXJS map operator to transform the data.

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-55hjnf)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  name = 'Angular';
  public data = {allPlans: [
    {id: 1, name: "strter", subscriber: 2500, amount: 0},
    {id: 2, name: "Pro_2500", subscriber: 2500, amount: 10},
    {id: 3, name: "Pro_5k", subscriber: 5000, amount: 20},
    {id: 4, name: "Pro_10k", subscriber: 10000, amount: 30},
    {id: 14, name: "Enterprise_2500", subscriber: 2500, amount: 100},
    {id: 15, name: "Enterprise_5k", subscriber: 5000, amount: 110},
    {id: 16, name: "Enterprise_10k", subscriber: 10000, amount: 120},
  ],
  starter: [],
  pro: [],
  enterprise: []};

  xdata: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(this.data);

  result: [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.xdata
    .pipe(
      map( d => {
        d.starter = d.allPlans.filter(f => f.name === 'strter');
        d.pro = d.allPlans.filter(f => f.name.substring(0, 3) === 'Pro');
        d.enterprise = d.allPlans.filter(f => f.name.substring(0, 10) === 'Enterprise');
        return d;
        })
    ).subscribe( d => {
      this.result = d;
    });
  }
}
```